# Do surreals prove reals are countable?

Tags: infinitesimals, surreal-numbers

If the surreal number $\epsilon = 1/\omega$ is the lower bound of the difference between any two real numbers (since it is smaller than any real number), and there are a countable number of these infinitesimals in any interval (since $1/\omega∗ω=1$), how are the reals in any interval not countable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mistake is your claim

> there are a countable number of these infinitesimals in any interval (since ${1\over \omega}\cdot\omega=1$).

You seem to be conflating the *surreal number* $\omega$ and the *countable ordinal* $\omega$. These are very different objects$^*$!

To get an initial hint of why your idea breaks down, consider the surreal number $\sqrt{\omega}$. It is infinite (= bigger than every natural number) but $<\omega$, and indeed $<{\omega\over n}$ for every natural number $n$. This means that we have $$0<{1\over\omega}<{2\over\omega}<{3\over\omega}<...<{\sqrt{\omega}\over\omega}={1\over\sqrt{\omega}}<{2\over\sqrt{\omega}}<{3\over\sqrt{\omega}}<...<{1\over 3}<{1\over 2}<{1\over 1}=1.$$ We can "add ${1\over\omega}$ to itself infinitely many times" and still wind up infinitesimal.

---

$^*$OK fine, they're the same object, but they're playing very different *roles*. E.g. there's no ordinal $\omega-1$, but there absolutely is a surreal number $\omega-1$, and so forth. The point is that in general **you can't transfer ideas about ordinals to ideas about surreals**, even about the surreals-which-are-ordinals. (And even when you can it takes work.)

Comment: Wouldn't $\omega \times \frac{1}{\omega}=1$? Which *is* infinitesimal w/ respect to $\omega$? Also, if 1 is 1st, wouldn't $\omega - 1$ be *last*?

Comment: @meowzz I don't understand your comment. Which part of my answer are you questioning?

Comment: "We can 'add $\frac{1}{ω}$ to itself infinitely many times' and still wind up infinitesimal." & "there's no ordinal $\omega−1$"

Comment: @meowzz $\sqrt{\omega}\over\omega$ - which is infinitesimal - is the result of adding ${1\over\omega}$ to itself $\sqrt{\omega}$ times, and $\sqrt{\omega}$ is infinite. (I didn't say we can add ${1\over\omega}$ to itself $\omega$-many times and still wind up infinitesimal!) Meanwhile, if you're familiar with the basics of ordinals then you know that there is indeed no ordinal $\omega-1$: $\omega$ is a *limit ordinal*. Only some surreal numbers "correspond to" ordinals, and the surreal number $\omega-1$ isn't one of these (even though $\omega$ is).